# Android Action Bar Title is not centered

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**action_bar_login.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/setup"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    final ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();

    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_login);
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

My goal is to center custom title in Action Bar, it does not work, because of the Back Button automatically margins title right, (a little bit, but noticeably). This code makes it center, but with back button, I want to avoid this one.

I tried some other solutions, but the result is same.

Thanks.

Comment: Add ` android:gravity="center"` in your xml.

Comment: thanks for response. I did this too, but still not working. it is centered but after the back button on the left side. so it looks like, it margins right a little bit.

Comment: Note that a centered action bar title is considered to not comply with the Android design guidelines. Watch [this Android Design in Action video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I) -- the centered-title anti-pattern (#5) appears at around the 14:00 mark.

Comment: Add actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); & use completly custom view.

Comment: whalaa, thank u my friend. I'll manage all menu from xml right now.

Answer (score 0):

use a`adroid:gravity = "center"`to sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.